# In Keras what's the best way to save a model checkpoint and reload it for training on different data set?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

So let's say I have a trained Keras neural network called model. I want to save the model before further training so I can go back to that checkpoint as I train it on different datasets.

```
model.save('checkpoint_1.h5')

model.fit(data_1, labels_1)

model.save('checkpoint_2.h5')
```

Now here's where my question comes in. I want to free up the GPU memory so I can reload checkpoint_1 before further training of the model. What I'm currently doing is ending the current tensorflow session and starting a new one.

```
from keras import backend as K
#End the current and start a new tensorflow session to free up gpu memory 
#to allow the next nn2 to be trained.
K.get_session().close()
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
```

I then load checkpoint_1 and continue training.

```
model = load_model('checkpoint_1.h5')

model.fit(data_2, labels_2)
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Stopping and starting the tensorflow sessions takes a lot of time.

Comment: You could train your network in a separate process - then every run would be performed in a different context - and after end of training it would be automatically cleaned up. This might help.